# delete a line beginning with N characters SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables SQL:

- USER with columns ->: uid, name, mail
- Phone ->: id, brand, model, refFirtUser

refFirtUser is a column that constitutes the user's id - and a random number
example : refFirtUser (uid_users-12345687) -> 9145-12345687

i want to delete in table "Phone" all data  .

I must to get "uid" of user by mail and to search N first characters before "-".

all data in column "refFirtUser " starting with "uid-xxxxx"
(where uid is the id of the user).
the only data I have is email

How should I do?

Comment: `WHERE refFirtUser LIKE '9145-%'` ?

Comment: i must to get this id.
you have to create a join to remove but I do not know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the from `phone` the user with mail `'someone@gmail.com'`:

```
delete from phone
where 
  refFirtUser like (select uid from user where mail = 'someone@gmail.com') || '-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous from your explanation whether `user.uid` is the number before `-` or after. In either case, you may use `exists`

```
delete from phone p 
      where exists ( select 1 from user u where mail in ( 'listofmail') 
 and p.refFirtUser like '%-'||u.id );
```

OR

```
delete from phone p 
      where exists ( select 1 from user u where mail in ( 'listofmail') 
 and p.refFirtUser like u.id||'-%' );
```

Comment: Thank's but this removes all data that contains "-"

Comment: @Ahmed : Your question needs improvement. Please edit it and add some sample rows of data and show what you want to achieve. It is hard to assume what you actually want just by reading your sentences